# Web Font Heights Cross Browser Behavior

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face, webfonts

Why do web fonts render differently between browsers, and what steps can be taken to fix the issue?

I'm having some issues with cross browser web font issues. I am absolutely positioning spans with single characters within them. Between browsers, the characters seem to be positioned the same relative to each other (within a few pixels).

However in IE, the grouping of characters is way off in relation to the rest of the flow of the document. The behavior when the characters are highlighted seems dramatically different in IE as well.

Does this have to do with font metrics? All 3 browsers are being rendered with a WOFF font.

Rendered in Chrome:

[image: Chrome No Highlight]
[image: Chrome Highlighted]

Rendered in Firefox:

[image: Firefox No Highlight]
[image: Firefox Highlighted]

Rendered in Internet Explorer:

[image: IE No Highlight]
[image: IE Highlight]

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<div style="border: 3px #000 solid; padding: 0px; line-height: 1; position: relative; width: 85.75px; height: 80px; font-size: 80px;">
    <span class="MathJax_Main" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">3</span>
    <span class="MathJax_MathItalic" style="position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 0;">x</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS used to load the web font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MathJax_Math';
    src: url('woff/MathJax_Math-Italic.woff') format('woff'),
        url('svg/MathJax_Math-Italic.svg#MathJax_Math') format('svg');
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MathJax_Main';
    src: url('woff/MathJax_Main-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('svg/MathJax_Main-Regular.svg#MathJax_Main') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
}

.MathJax_MathItalic {
    font-family: 'MathJax_Math';
    font-style: italic;
}

.MathJax_Main {
    font-family: 'MathJax_Main';
}
```

Comment: where's the rest of the code? (e.g. where's the CSS that loads in the webfont, which font is being loaded, if you're using MathJax why is this plain HTML instead of `\$3x$\` for inline math typesetting, etc?)

Comment: I edited the original post to include the CSS used to load the fonts. I'm not using the MathJax library, because I'm building an editor. I tried initially writing an extension for the library, but couldn't quite get it to work, so I decided to go from scratch using their fonts.

[Example App](http://camdenre.github.io/src/app/html/EquationEditor)
||
[Source](https://github.com/camdenre/equation-editor)

Comment: no definition for `MathJax_Math`? Also, don't use [SVG fonts](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20font), it's been deprecated entirely (in fact SVG glyphs [are now part](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/svg.htm) of the OpenType standard instead). If you have a WOFF, [that's all you need](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff)

Comment: hm, so I just tried your example app in IE11 and it renders perfectly fine. Which IE were you trying? (If 8: MS no longer supports that, nor the OS it runs on. Both are EOL. If 9: any real user on IE9 is on a version of windows that should be running 11 now)

Comment: My example app uses javascript to manually offset for internet explorer. Here is a full example of the issue [jsbin example issue](http://jsbin.com/darecohoyo/1/edit?html,css,output). If you open it in IE11 and chrome, you'll see the differences in rendering.

Comment: Here is an example manually offsetting the top values using javascript [jsbin javascript fix](http://jsbin.com/gadohohuju/1/edit?html,css,js,output).